# How to say "A Map of Class<?> to List<The class>" in Java?

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

Say I have a

```
HashMap<?, List<?>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(String.class, new ArrayList<Long>());
```

The following code will compile.

However, I want to fail compilation because the ArrayList is not for String type.

Also, my wildcard is limited to some specific interface (e.g. Exception), so I suppose I should put that `<? extends Exception>` somewhere.

How can I achieve the above?

Example Test:

```
map.put(String.class, new ArrayList<String>()); //Fail because String is not an Exception
map.put(IOException.class, new ArrayList<FileNotFoundException>()); // Fail because FileNotFoundException is not an IOException even though it is a subclass of it
map.put(FileNotFoundException.class, new ArrayList<IOException>()); // I suppose I'm fine with this.
map.put(IllegalArgumentException.class, new ArrayList<IllegalArgumentException>()); // Succeed
map.put(NumberFormatException.class, new ArrayList<ServerException>()); // Fail again because the two classes don't match
map.put(ClientDecodingException.class, new ArrayList<ClientDecodingException.class>); // Succeed again since the map takes in a wildcard Exception
```

Comment: What about `Map<Class<T>, List<T>>`?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza that would require `<T>` to be declared somewhere, and then your map could only contain classes/lists of that type -- you couldn't have both T=String and T=IOException.

Comment: @yshavit you can have a `class MapOfClass` that works as a wrapper for a `Map<Class, List>` (I will use raw types just as an example) and has a method `public <T> List<T> put(Class<T> clazz, List<T>> list)`. It's more verbose but can solve OP's problem.

Comment: It's one of the workaround, yes. (You don't even need raws, you can just have a `Map<Class<?>, List<?>>`.) But the OP's specific requirements can't be done in Java.

Comment: I'm new to java but couldn't you just define your own hashmap class which extends hashmap and overloading "put" such that it is not generic but only accepts exception types as argumen?

Comment: @HyperZ in cases like this, it's better to use composition over inheritance.

Comment: Thanks all, I suspected so but just wanted to check with the community if I missed anything =) @LuiggiMendoza: I'm interested in hearing the composition over inheritance approach, what do you mean, mind providing a concrete example?

Answer (score 1):

I beleive you can't express such a generic constraint between your map's key and value on declaration. You could declare the map as a

```
    Map<Class<Exception>, List<Exception>>
```

but then the compiler won't know that the exceptions in the list must extend the key's class.

I don't see a lot of ways of ensuring this constraint is checked except by using a method such as

```
    <T extends Exception> void addToMap(Class<? extends T> aClass, List<T> aList) { 
        map.put(aClass, aList); 
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this by using raw `Class` and `List` (still cannot *fix* this) and by using a map wrapper for storing `Exception` only:

```
public class ExceptionMapWrapper {

    private Map<Class, List> myMap;

    public ExceptionMapWrapper() {
        myMap = new HashMap<>();
    }
    //relevant methods for the test: put and get
    public <T extends Exception> void put(Class<T> clazz, List<T> list) {
        myMap.put(clazz, list);
    }

    public <T extends Exception> List<T> get(Class<T> key) {
        return myMap.get(key);
    }
}
```

And a simple test for this:

```
ExceptionMapWrapper exceptionMapWrapper = new ExceptionMapWrapper();
Class<IOException> clazz = IOException.class;
List<IOException> list = new ArrayList<>();
exceptionMapWrapper.put(clazz, list);
//compiler errors, uncomment to see them
//exceptionMapWrapper.put(String.class, new ArrayList<String>());
//exceptionMapWrapper.put(IOException.class, new ArrayList<ClassCastException>());
//exceptionMapWrapper.put(IOException.class, new ArrayList<SQLException>());
List<IOException> ioExList = exceptionMapWrapper.get(clazz);
//compiler error, uncomment to see
//List<SQLException> sqlExList = exceptionMapWrapper.get(clazz);
```