# Java Generics Map Key-Value Typing

Tags: java, generics, collections

I'm wanting a method to return something like

```
Map<Class<T>, List<T>>
```

where the map's keys correspond to lists of instances of that class, but the map can contain many different types of classes.  Is there a way to enforce that the typing of the key and value must correspond, while allowing all different types to be stored in the map?

Comment: Not directly. Here's an approach using composition and raw types I've done in another post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30401363/1065197. Note that for that case, OP needed that the map contains `Exception` classes only. You may remove that boundary from the code.

Comment: agree, java generics is not expressive enough to do that.

Comment: Are you expecting a key to be an instance of a class or the class itself?